# Gridview update a column using another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, databound

I have a gridview bound with a database. I would like to add an extra column which has a linkbutton. The intention is that when clicked on the linkbutton, the user could toggle the value of a column which is bounded with the database.

I don't have any good ideas how to get started on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards, Thijs

Comment: Thank you both for your quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question,

Make you `gridview` template fields. you can find more about [Using TemplateFields in the GridView Control](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)

Place the `linkbutton` with a `commandname`. See [ButtonField.CommandName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx)

In here do the same for the field you need to access. You will be able to access the values and change as you need.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Right the way I would approach this is declare a class called GridRecord or something that represents a grid row.

```
class GridRecord
{
}
```

then in the class define all properties that will be the columns of your grid including the link column.

```
class GridRecord
{
    private Image m_Link = [some image];
    public GridRecord(){}

    public Image Link
    {
        get { return m_Link; }
    }
}
```

then in your grid code:

```
IList<GridRecord> records = new List<GridRecords>();
//Fill records object as you like.
Grid1.DataSource = records;
```

Then handle the RowCellClick or similar event and check if the clicked cell is of property type Link and use it.